# Sub panel in seperate structure

Tags: subpanel

I am installing a sub panel in my shed about 100 feet away from house. I am using a 50 amp breaker with 6 nhhn wire. Can i use a grounding rod to ground instead of running wire back to main. And do i need to run a neutral back to main box.

Comment: This demonstrates a complete lack of appropriate research into a rather serious undertaking. You need a 4 wire feed (hot, hot, neutral, ground) ground and neutral must be separated at the sub panel (which is one reason you need both wires back to the main panel) AND you need a grounding electrode system at the separate structure, connected to the ground wire.

Comment: Are you wanting to directly bury the wires, or are you putting a conduit in?

Answer (score 2):

### Fat conduit is your friend here

Based on what you're indicating, it seems you want to run THHN in conduit between the two structures, which is decidedly a Good Thing because conduit gives you the power to upgrade in the future if you wish.  I would run a 1.5" or 2" PVC conduit (Schedule 80 for stub-ups, Schedule 40 for the buried part), buried 21-22" deep, with a 1" Schedule 40 beside it for telecom wiring if I were in your shoes.  This provides ample expansion space for mains power (up to 125A, if not more), as well as the ability to get Ethernet, fiber, or some other sort of communications cable out to the shed in the future if you so desire.

### You'll need four wires *and* ground rods, both

However, your understanding of neutrals, bonding, and grounding is far shorter than it needs to be.  For just about all of us, neutral and ground meet at one place only; namely, the *main bonding jumper* in your service equipment.  Everywhere else, they need to be *isolated* from each other, which means that you *must* run four wires for your feeder: two hots, a neutral, and a grounding wire.  This provides two return paths for current: the neutral as the "normal" way power gets back to the utility, and the grounding wire as an emergency safety drain to return wayward utility electricity back to the utility.

Furthermore, you'll *also* need grounding rods at the shed, in order to send *natural* electricity (such as induced charges from lightning strikes) back to nature.  In most places, two ground rods driven 8' deep and set 8' apart will suffice; you'll need to connect them to each other and to the shed's breaker box with an unbroken length of 6AWG copper wire to form your *grounding electrode system* at the shed.

### As to that box...

Your shed will need a breaker box of its own, with its own main breaker in it to serve as a shutoff for the shed.  This is no place to chintz out on, even for a small shed; breaker spaces go quickly, so a 24 or 30 space, 125A, main breaker panel is not at all out of place here!  Note that you'll need to make sure that the green neutral-to-ground bonding screw or bonding Z-strap is *removed* from the panel when it is installed, and you'll also need to install a matching accessory *ground bar* into the panel if it does not come with one factory fitted.

When wiring the shed branch circuits, as well, you'll need to make sure that the branch circuit neutrals *all* land on neutral bars (or on GFCI breaker load neutrals) and the branch circuit grounds *all* land on the grounding bar(s).  The aforementioned 6AWG wire from your ground rods needs to land on a grounding bar, too.